# Meteor with google translate

Tags: meteor, google-translate

I am new to Meteor and would like to convert a small app of mine into meteor.
I need my app to connect and use google translate API.
How can I do that with meteor??

Answer (score 3):

The [percolate:google-api](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/google-api) package is a general wrapper for the google api and you can use it to make calls to the google translate api

Comment: Thanks Serkan, it is a useful site.

Comment: Your welcome. By the way, if you think my answer satisfies your question, you should mark it as accepted so that other people coming to this page know it is.